# Find number of divisors for integer and sum of integers

Tags: optimization, c, mathematics

1. This function computes and returns the number of divisors an integer has. But it is very slow and I believe it can be optimized for speed.

   ```
   unsigned long long int find_no_of_divisors(unsigned long long int myno,FILE *ifp)
   {

       unsigned long long int divsrs = 2;    
       unsigned long long int k = 2;

       if(myno == 1)
       {
           return 1;
       }

       if(myno == 2)
       {
           return 2;
       }

       while(1)
       {
           if((myno % k) == 0)
           {           
               divsrs++;
               if(divsrs == MY_ULLONG_MAX)
               {
                   printf("Overflow detected in the calculated value for divisors of a number... Exiting");
                   fclose(ifp);
                   exit(-1);
               }           
           }

           k++;        

           if(k > (myno/2))
           {
               break;
           }
       }

       return divsrs;
   }
   ```
2. This one computes and returns the sum of first *n* integers:

   ```
   unsigned long long int next_no(unsigned long long int idx,unsigned long long int cur_no,FILE *ifp)
   {
       unsigned long long int next_no;

       next_no = ((idx)*(idx + 1))/2;

       if((next_no - idx) != cur_no)
       {
           printf("Overflow detected in the value of the calculated number... Exiting");
           fclose(ifp);
           exit(-1);
       }
       return next_no;
   }
   ```

Could there be any glitches or functionality issues? (PS - I did not want to use a `sqrt()` function due to my portability constraints.)

Comment: I believe the formatting was messed up a bit due to the numberings in your question, adding some extra spacing seemed to have solved it.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks. Yes i tried but couldn't fix it.

Comment: You should give some context for the second function. From the code it looks to me as if you're iterating from 0 to some number N and on each iteration calling `next_no` with the current index and the result from the last call of `next_no`. So you're basically calculating the sum from 0 to `idx` for each `idx` from 0 to `N`. However for now that's just me guessing, so you should be more specific about that.

Comment: @sepp2k:Yes, I am computing summation of integers uptox idx for each idx passed in. And this function can be called with idx value possibly from 0 to ULLONG_MAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first function can be sped up by just iterating up to `sqrt(myno)` and adding 2 instead of 1 to `divsrs` when `k` divides `myno` unless `k` is the square root of `myno` (in which case you would only add 1).

The second function already takes constant, but you can get rid of the multiplication and division, by simply returning `cur_no + idx` and using `cur_no < ULLONG_MAX - idx` to check whether there'd be an overflow.

---

Now a couple of style notes on the code:

First of all, it seems strange to me to pass the file handle to the functions, if they don't actually write to (or read from) the file. I see that you did so you could close the file before exiting the program in case of an overflow. I would rather recommend that you return an error value when an overflow occurs and then close the file and exit in the calling code.

Further your `while(1)` loop in `find_no_of_divisors` is actually a pretty plain `for`-loop and should be written as one. No need for complicated control flow for something so simple.

Lastly I would not recommend dropping (some) vowels from variable names like you do in `divsrs` - that just leads to typos.

Comment: The first change may not be appropriate - if he really wants all the divisors (not just prime factors) then I think his way is the only way to do it.

Comment: @DHall: Can you give an example where the algorithm I outlined would not give the correct number of divisors? It definitely does not return the number of prime factors.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. Your way is correct.

Comment: Edited my OP. Can u pls. check OP again and see if this code incorporates the optimizations correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to sepp2k's excellent answer some math that could help you:

If you have the prime factors of a number, you just take the exponents, increase every one by one and take the product.

```
E.g. 12 = 2^2 * 3^1 -> [2,1] -(+1)-> [3,2] -> 6
12 has 6 divisors: 1,2,3,4,6,12 

E.g. 100 = 2^2 * 5^2 -> [2,2] -(+1)-> [3,3] -> 9
100 has 9 divisors: 1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100
```

The smallest divisor of a number (greater than 1) is always prime. The algorithm in pseudocode looks like (untested):

```
divisors(N) {
  result = 1
  for (p = 2; p <= sqrt(N); p++) { //check all divisors
     if (n mod p == 0) {
        for(f = 0; n mod p == 0; n = n / p) { //try to divide as often as possible
           f++  //count how often we divide
        }
        result = result * (f+1)  
     }  
  }
  if (N == 1) return result //number completely factored
  else return 2 //then we found no factor -> N itself is prime 
}
```